# Navigation drawer toggle icon is not visible

Tags: android, navigation

Im using the following code to setup navigation drawer but the icon of navigation drawer is not visible.

```
public class NavigationDrawer extends ActionBarActivity {
private int mPosition = -1;
private String mTitle = "";
private String[] mDashBoardList;

private int[] mIcons = new int[]{R.drawable.dashboard,
        R.drawable.my_orders, R.drawable.testimonials,
        R.drawable.notifications, R.drawable.contact_us, R.drawable.sync,
        R.drawable.logout};

private String[] mCount = new String[]{"", "", "", "", "", "", "",};

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private LinearLayout mDrawer;
private List<HashMap<String, String>> mList;
private SimpleAdapter mAdapter;
final private String DRAWER_CONTENT = "vaighai";
final private String FLAG = "flag";
final private String COUNT = "count";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_main);

    mDashBoardList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawerContents);

    mTitle = (String) getTitle();

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_lists);

    mDrawer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

    mList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put(DRAWER_CONTENT, mDashBoardList[i]);
        hm.put(COUNT, mCount[i]);
        hm.put(FLAG, Integer.toString(mIcons[i]));
        mList.add(hm);
    }

    String[] from = {FLAG, DRAWER_CONTENT, COUNT};

    int[] to = {R.id.flag, R.id.country, R.id.count};

    mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mList, R.layout.drawer_layout, from,
            to);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            highlightSelectedItem();
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };


    if (mDrawer != null)
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {

            // incrementHitCount(position);

            if (position < 5) {
                showFragment(position);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        mDashBoardList[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawer);
        }
    });

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#2cc3b7"));
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void incrementHitCount(int position) {
    HashMap<String, String> item = mList.get(position);
    String count = item.get(COUNT);
    item.remove(COUNT);
    if (count.equals("")) {
        count = "  1  ";
    } else {
        int cnt = Integer.parseInt(count.trim());
        cnt++;
        count = "  " + cnt + "  ";
    }
    item.put(COUNT, count);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void showFragment(int position) {

    mTitle = mDashBoardList[position];

    DrawerFragment cFragment = new DrawerFragment();

    Bundle data = new Bundle();

    data.putInt("position", position);

    cFragment.setArguments(data);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, cFragment);

    ft.commit();

}

public void highlightSelectedItem() {
    int selectedItem = mDrawerList.getCheckedItemPosition();

    if (selectedItem > 4)
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(mPosition, true);
    else
        mPosition = selectedItem;

    if (mPosition != -1)
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDashBoardList[mPosition]);
}

@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}


}
```

I have used mDrawerToggle.syncState() but still the problem persists. I have also tried setting 
`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` to `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);` 
But not Work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write `mDrawerToggle.syncState();` after you initialize `mDrawerToggle` somthing like this

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
        R.string.drawer_close) {

    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        highlightSelectedItem();
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
};

mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

usually everyone is using toolbar but as you are not with `ActionBarActivity`.
I would like to mention that `ActionBar` is been deprecated.

you might want to try using default `NavigationActivity` provided by the Android Studio

Comment: @user1241241, are you using Android studio?

Comment: kindly use toolbar as Action bar has been deprecated, you might want to extend your activity with AppCompactActivity while using toolbar

Answer (score 1):

Add this line:

```
       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Of course, check your xml file on the toolbar's id, the default should be toolbar tho.

Comment: i have not used any toolbar in my xml

Comment: im using drawerlayout

Comment: yes, me too, and looking at my xml files, i have one called app_bar_navigation_drawer and in it a toolbar like this 
`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />`

Comment: I've used the Android Studio template Navigation Drawer activity and everything is working :)

Comment: well the only line I see you missing is the toolbar, and in the toolbar is the 3 parallel lines that open the nav. drawer. Are you referring to that?